# convert pixel alpha channel when alpha > 90% using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, alpha-transparency

I need to convert existing png 2 areas files : one area is transparent and the other is red or blue opaque (one sample here : http://urlz.fr/31t2).
I want to keep the first area tranparent and to convert opaque area to 30 or 50% of opacity.
I'm desperatly looking for a solution using Imagemagick, as a radio engineer i'm not comfortable with the IM ressources ...
I'm only able to convert the whole image to X% of opacity (convert input.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 50% output.png
)but that's not what i am looking for !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but I think you want this:

```
convert image.png -channel A -fx "u>0.9?0.3:u" result.png
```

Wherever the alpha is more than 0.9, it will be set to 0.3, otherwise it will be untouched.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help, if you have any idea to convert the same way a list of files and keeping as part of output filename the input name ? (input00.png => input00_modified.png)

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix/Linux machine?

Comment: Just find the answer after writing the question (i'm using windows) : [imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/#for_loops)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick and accurate answer to my not so accurate question!
That looks like something i have just found (excepted the use of "u" as a variable rather than a value) :

```
convert input -channel A -fx "(a>0.99)?0.3:0" output
```

For sure, your writing is more elegant !